# Replace default Drupal Garland theme during installation

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-distributions

I'm writing an installation profile and want to switch default system theme (Garland) to my own theme. The theme should replace Garland on the first step - when I choose installation profile. On this stage Drupal is not bootstrapped, so I can not set appropriate DB variables.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to replace the theme early in the install? Garland is well tested and could prevent unaccounted for theme errors within your custom theme.

Comment: Side note, it's actually the 'Minnelli' Garland sub-theme that's used, not Garland. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. It's fairly hard-coded in [_drupal_maintenance_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.maintenance.inc/function/_drupal_maintenance_theme/6):

```
// Install and update pages are treated differently to prevent theming overrides.
if (defined('MAINTENANCE_MODE') && (MAINTENANCE_MODE == 'install' || MAINTENANCE_MODE == 'update')) {
  $theme = 'minnelli';
}
```